# VBA Function to Filter Pivot Table Based on Option Button Form Control

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table that has a column containing text. I also have 5 option buttons. Via VBA code I would like to filter a column of the pivot table if it CONTAINS a certain text. I would need five different contains functions to account for the various combinations. I then plan to assign these macros to the option buttons. I've browsed various forums but couldn't get it to work as they described it and they never built it exactly how I'm describing it here.

This is what I have so far for 3 of the buttons, but I'm getting an error when I click off one button and onto another:

```
Sub Incr_Phys()
'
' Incr_Phys Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Eligible Win Type"). _
        PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Incr Phys"
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
End Sub
Sub All_Win_Types()
'
' All_Win_Types Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Eligible Win Type"). _
        PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="?"
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
End Sub
Sub Acq()
'
' Acq Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Eligible Win Type"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Eligible Win Type"). _
        PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Acq"
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You'd have to combine the state of each of the checkboxes into a filter for your table. What does your code look like?

Comment: @peterT --> I actually opted back for the radio button and added one that read "All". So there are 6 radio buttons in total. If one of the five are selected then the table should filter on values that contain that specific text. If "All" is selected then it should filter on values that contain any one of the 5 specific texts. So now I'm at square one again!

Comment: @PeterT, I've added my current code here for the first three buttons. However, its telling me there's a bug when using the radio buttons...around this area: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Eligible Win Type"). _
        PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Incr Phys"

Answer (score 0):

It's clear you've recorded a macro to capture the VBA as an example of where to start. Very good move, because that can reveal some of the methods you wouldn't otherwise know about. Once you've done that, there are a few things you can do to help debug the code and help see what's happening more clearly.

1. Edit the code to remove `Activate` and `Select`.
2. Define and set references to `Worksheets` and `Workbooks`. It will help you avoid problems later on when you try to expand your work.
3. When you're having an unknown issue, break apart the individual pieces of a single compound statement. That way you can isolate exactly which part of the action is giving you the error. I've done this below to access different parts of your `PivotTable`

What I think you were missing is to `ClearAllFilters` before re-applying a new filter.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Incr_Phys()
'
' Incr_Phys Macro
'
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim pivotWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set pivotWS = thisWB.Sheets("Sheet5")

    Dim thisPT As PivotTable
    Dim winType As PivotField
    Set thisPT = pivotWS.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set winType = thisPT.PivotFields("Eligible Win Type")
    With winType
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Incr Phys"
    End With
End Sub
```